# Why does time to count X entities in GAE Datastore increase with total number of entities?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I ran some tests to count the number of entities of kind X in the Google App Engine Datastore, with a count limit of 5000. To my surprise, the time taken by this operation **increases** as the total number of entities of kind X increases in the Datastore.

If the count operation is simply walking the index on keys of the entity, shouldn't the time be constant (so long as total count > 5000) irrespective of the total number of entities of kind X in the Datastore?

[**NB:** This is not about whether to use sharded counters or to use Datastore statistics, it's about the results of my tests being counter-intuitive.]

**Update 1:** Testing on `devserver`.

Here is some data:

```
Time to create & save 100000 entities: 35.92 s
Using Objectify:
Individual times of 10 runs: 14795, 9521, 9300, 9117, 9848, 9391, 8378, 8525, 8593, 8706
Average time to count 5000 entities over 10 runs: 9.617 seconds
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Using Datastore:
Individual times of 10 runs: 8984, 8827, 9062, 9160, 8768, 8737, 8488, 8523, 8828, 8956
Average time to count 5000 entities over 10 runs: 8.833 seconds
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Time to create & save 50000 entities: 20.03 s
Using Objectify:
Individual times of 10 runs: 5877, 4736, 4162, 4252, 4126, 4203, 4153, 4168, 4051, 4110
Average time to count 5000 entities over 10 runs: 4.384 seconds
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Using Datastore:
Dec 16, 2015 10:00:36 AM in.co.amebatechnologies.empireapp.test.DatastoreTests tearDown
INFO: Closing this session
Individual times of 10 runs: 4409, 4380, 4577, 4414, 4121, 4050, 4076, 4050, 4089, 4148
Average time to count 5000 entities over 10 runs: 4.231 seconds
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Time to create & save 10000 entities: 8.989 s
Using Objectify:
Individual times of 10 runs: 1893, 802, 713, 678, 679, 657, 648, 654, 659, 654
Average time to count 5000 entities over 10 runs: 0.804 seconds
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Using Datastore:
Individual times of 10 runs: 923, 789, 871, 680, 677, 694, 680, 682, 728, 682
Average time to count 5000 entities over 10 runs: 0.741 seconds
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Using:

- GAE SDK 1.9.30
- Objectify 5.1.7

Code to count entities in Datastore directly (i.e., without using `Objectify`):

```
DatastoreService ds = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query qry = new com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query();
qry.setKeysOnly();
PreparedQuery prepQry = ds.prepare(qry);
FetchOptions fetchOpts = FetchOptions.Builder.withOffset(0).limit(5000).chunkSize(1000);
// Time this operation only:
prepQry.countEntities(fetchOpts);
```

Comment: This question isn't really about programming but about why googles infrastructure works the way it does. I suggest you read up on some of the architecture docs that google has published.  With regards to the datastore, counting more records takes more work hence increasing time.  Not sure why you see this as counter intuitive.

Comment: I am asking Datastore for the entity count, but only up to a limit of 5000 (i.e., "stop when counter hits 5000"). Time to do that shouldn't vary with the total number of records.

Comment: Are you testing this on the dev server or in production ?

Comment: Testing on the dev server.

Comment: I don't think dev server can provide relevant results for such testing

Comment: Yep, you can't draw any conclusions about performance from the dev server. The dev server is running an in memory copy of sqlite.

Answer (score 2):

The development server provides local emulation of the production environment, including Datastore (documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/devserver?hl=en#Using_the_Datastore)).  However, the Datastore emulation does not have the same performance characteristics for large datasets.

When I run your code to count entities in the production Datastore environment, from 10,000 to 100,000 entities, the average times across 10 runs are consistent:

```
Total Entities: 20000
Run 0: Time to count 5000 entities: 242
Run 1: Time to count 5000 entities: 352
Run 2: Time to count 5000 entities: 215
Run 3: Time to count 5000 entities: 244
Run 4: Time to count 5000 entities: 241
Run 5: Time to count 5000 entities: 221
Run 6: Time to count 5000 entities: 258
Run 7: Time to count 5000 entities: 219
Run 8: Time to count 5000 entities: 260
Run 9: Time to count 5000 entities: 219
Average: 247.1

Total Entities: 50000
Run 0: Time to count 5000 entities: 346
Run 1: Time to count 5000 entities: 236
Run 2: Time to count 5000 entities: 214
Run 3: Time to count 5000 entities: 353
Run 4: Time to count 5000 entities: 244
Run 5: Time to count 5000 entities: 229
Run 6: Time to count 5000 entities: 244
Run 7: Time to count 5000 entities: 257
Run 8: Time to count 5000 entities: 216
Run 9: Time to count 5000 entities: 224
Average: 256.3

Total Entities: 100000
Run 0: Time to count 5000 entities: 215
Run 1: Time to count 5000 entities: 212
Run 2: Time to count 5000 entities: 329
Run 3: Time to count 5000 entities: 217
Run 4: Time to count 5000 entities: 230
Run 5: Time to count 5000 entities: 231
Run 6: Time to count 5000 entities: 225
Run 7: Time to count 5000 entities: 222
Run 8: Time to count 5000 entities: 273
Run 9: Time to count 5000 entities: 306
Average: 246.0
```